# play video in app through video out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

http://www.google.com/products/catalog?oe=UTF-8&gfns=1&q=iphone+video+out+cable&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=17045329161497634089&ei=JpU1TcymOcnogQfC25C7Cw&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CCgQ8wIwBA#

I want to know if its possible to play video from an app through a lead like this onto a TV or something similar. I've heard that the functionality is not available in apps. Is this true?

If its not true and its perfectly possible what exactly is possible? Is it possible to push a different video output to the external TV as that that is on the device?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that cable will have the same functionality as a connector for a projector or second display right?

If that is the case then the answer is: **IS POSSIBLE**.

But, everything that is want to show in the second display have to be explicitly done by you. There is no mirroring system or something alike.

Read here, there is a sample app also :)
http://mattgemmell.com/2010/06/01/ipad-vga-output